# Solving $\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{16-x^2}dx $ by substitution compared to a formula

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to solve the integral

$$
\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{16-x^2} \mathrm dx 
$$

I used the substitution method.

### What I did

$$
x = 4 \sin t \implies dx = 4 \cos t
$$

Therefore, we get

\begin{align}
\sqrt{16-x^2} &= \sqrt{16-16 \sin^2 t} = \sqrt{16(1-\sin^2 t)} = 4 \cos t \end{align}

and

\begin{align}
t &= \arcsin \left(\dfrac x 4 \right) \\
\implies x &= 2 \to t = \arcsin \left (\dfrac 12 \right) \\
\implies x &= 4 \to t = \arcsin (1)
\end{align}

which yields

$$
\displaystyle \int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{16-x^2} \mathrm dx = \int_{\arcsin \left(\frac 12 \right)}^{\arcsin (1)} 16 \cos^2 t \mathrm dt 
$$

But the answers got (did direct integration by a formula)

[image]

How did they get this? And if I'm wrong, then what have I done wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: "what have I done wrong?": stopping at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Going from your last line, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\arcsin1/2}^{\arcsin1}16\cos^2t\,dt&=\int_{\arcsin1/2}^{\arcsin1}16\cdot\frac12(1+\cos2t)\,dt\\
&=\int_{\arcsin1/2}^{\arcsin1}\frac{16}2+\frac{16}2\cos2t\,dt\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{16}2t+\frac{16}2\cdot\frac12\sin2t\right)\right|_{\arcsin1/2}^{\arcsin1}\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{16}2t+8\sin t\cos t\right)\right|_{\arcsin1/2}^{\arcsin1}\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{16}2\arcsin\frac{x}4+8\cdot\frac{x}4\cdot\frac14\sqrt{16-x^2}\right)\right|_{4\sin\arcsin1/2}^{4\sin\arcsin1}\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{16}2\arcsin\frac{x}4+\frac{x}2\sqrt{16-x^2}\right)\right|_{2}^{4}\\
\end{align} as desired.

---

You can also evaluate this integral geometrically.  We want to calculate the shaded area in the figure. [image: visual of integral]

We have the shaded area as the area of the sector less the area of the triangle.  Therefore:

\begin{align}
A&=\frac12\theta r^2-\frac12\cdot2\cdot4\sin\theta\\
&=\frac12\cdot\frac\pi3\cdot16-2{\sqrt3}\\
&=\frac{8\pi}3-2\sqrt3\approx4.913.
\end{align}

Link to desmos https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lhgu44wfl2

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_2^4 \sqrt{16 - x^2} dx &= \int_{arcsin(1/2)}^{arcsin{1}} 16cos^2t dt \\
                  &= \int_{arcsin(1/2)}^{arcsin(1)} 16(\frac{1 + cos (2t)}{2})dt\\
                  &= \left[16\left(\frac{t}{2} + \frac{sin(2t)}{4}\right)\right]_{arcsin(1/2)}^{arcsin(1)}
\end{align}

Now, substitute $t = arcsin(x/4)$ in the above expression and $sin(2t) = 2sin(t)cos(t) = 2sin(t)\sqrt{1-sin^2(t)} = 2\frac{x}{4}\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{4})^2} = \frac{x}{8}\sqrt{16-x^2}$, we get after reverting to the original limits in $x$
\begin{align}
\int_2^4 \sqrt{16 - x^2} dx &=\left[\frac{16}{2}arcsin(x/4) + \frac{16}{4}\frac{x}{8}\sqrt{16-x^2}\right]_{2}^{4} \\
   &= \left[\frac{16}{2}arcsin(x/4) + \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{16-x^2}\right]_{2}^{4}
\end{align}

Hope it answers!

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{16-x^2}dx=\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac {16-x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx$$
$$I=\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac {16}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx-\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac {x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx$$
$$I=16\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac {d(x/4)}{\sqrt{1-(x/4)^2}}+\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac {x(-2x)}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx$$
Integrate by part the second integral. The first one is obvious.
$$2I=16\int_{2}^{4}\dfrac {d(x/4)}{\sqrt{1-(x/4)^2}}+ \left |x(\sqrt{16-x^2})\right|_2^4$$
$$2I=\left|16\arcsin (x/4)+x(\sqrt{16-x^2})\right|_2^4$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$(x\sqrt{16-x^2})'=\sqrt{16-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}
\\=\sqrt{16-x^2}+\frac{16-x^2-16}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}
\\=2\sqrt{16-x^2}-\frac{16}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$

and

$$\left(\arcsin\frac x4\right)'=\frac1{4\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{16}}}=\frac1{\sqrt{16-x^2}}.$$

Then

$$\int_2^4\sqrt{16-x^2}\,dx=\left.\frac{x\sqrt{16-x^2}+16\arcsin\dfrac x4}2\right|_2^4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (often) it is useful to depict what you are computing:

[image]

The area of the red region equals the area of a circle sector (corresponding to an angle $\frac{2\pi}{6}$) minus the area of a right triangle. It follows that

$$ \int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{16-x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \pi 4^2 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\sqrt{3} = \color{red}{\frac{8}{3}\pi-\sqrt{3}}.$$